# Time Complexity - Insertion Vs Merge on a "mostly" sorted list

Tags: java, time

I have a question. I'm currently taking a class on Object Oriented Programming with Data Structures, and there was a question on a quiz that I apparently got wrong.

"Which of the following search algorithms is the fastest at sorting a 1-D array which is already mostly sorted?"

The answers listed were: Quick Sort, Insertion Sort, Merge Sort, Selection Sort

I wasn't sure how large the lists were, so I chose Insertion sort because I know that O(n) would be the best case time complexity for a mostly sorted list that wasn't too large. The correct answer for it was Merge sort. I decided to run some tests and, for a mostly sorted list of 500, the results showed that Insertion sort was the fastest. However, I know that Merge sort would win if the list were larger. When I asked why Insertion sort would not also be an answer, I received replies stating that I'm always to assume that the lists in these questions are very large lists and to always assume worst case. No one could provide me any documentation on that answer, so that's why I'm here. When asked a question like this, am I to always assume the worst case and that the list will be large?

Comment: for small data sets the difference in perfomance for any algorithm is so small that it makes the most sense to use the simplest implemention, i.e. insertion sort in your case. In many cases, the overhead from a more complex implementation with a theroretically better perfomance often leads to worse performance. Also the data structure of your list plays a big role, i.e. you cant compare linked lists to array lists for example, both have  their ups and downs

Answer (score 0):

I think in this particular case it has to be said that the quiz question is rather ill-defined. I mean what is *mostly sorted*. The worst case for merge sort is `O(nlog(n))` so unless *mostly sorted* means `< log(n)` is sorted, then merge wins. Otherwise I think you would be correct. The size of the list doesn't really matter.